# component shows prevoius state for a second before update in mui Alert

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, components, alert

I have one Form page for user registration where an alert is shown whenever I have any error from an API, so I made this Alert component

```
    <Snackbar
    open={open}
    autoHideDuration={9000}
    onClose={() => {
      setOpen(false);
    }}
  >
    <Alert
      severity={type}
      onClose={() => {
        setOpen(false);
      }}
    >
      {msg}
    </Alert>
  </Snackbar>
```

and in user registration form I have one state open that's become true whenever user click on user create button

```
<Button
            variant="contained"
            type="submit"
            id="root"
            sx={{
              width: "25%",
             
            }}
            onClick={()=> setOpen(true)}
          >
            Create
</Button>
```

my alert component also called in user registration form, alert and msg are set basis on the post from data api responses

```
{alert ? <Alert msg={msg} type={type} setOpen={setOpen} open={open} setMsg={setMsg}/> : ""}
```

But the problem is alert popup always shows previous error first for a second then actual error.

I have open, msg and all states in my form component.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well recently and a trick I did is something like this:

```js
{isOpen && <Snackbar>
   ...
</Snackbar>
}
```

My understanding is that the Snackbar isn't fully unmounted so the previous message still exists for a brief second. But that's as far as I could tell. Can you try this approach and tell me if it works?

Comment: no it doen't work for me

Comment: so it still flashes the old error before updating?

Comment: yes , just for a second